# Mojave - How can I lower the lowest volume?

Tags: audio, mojave

Currently I'm at 1/4 volume (option+shift+volume) but it is still loud.

All of the systemic solutions are out of date or about limiting maximum volume.

Is there a way to permanently lower the lowest volume?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to lower the lowest volume permanently, but there is a way to make it **temporarily**, as long as you don't press the volume button after using this command.

Just enter this into terminal:

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 3.5"
```

and it will set it to 50% volume, using 0 for no volume, 7 for max. 1/4 is around 0.57, so

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 0.57"
```

will set it to that 1/4 increment. If you want lower, you can use:

```
sudo osascript -e "set Volume 0.2"
```

etc, etc. Adjust to whatever fits.